# リリース版で OnNewToken イベントが起きない(Xamarin forms VS2019)

Tags: android, xamarin, push-notification

VisualStudio 2019 Xamarin forms のデバッグ版でAndroid実機に接続して
（最初に）起動すると正しく Token が取得できますが、
Google Play Console のオープンテストから実機にインストールして起動すると、
OnNewToken イベントが起きず Token が取得できないで困っています。

#### 試したこと

強制的に初期化して実施してみたけれど OnNewToke イベントは起きませんでした。
FirebasePushNotificationManager.Initialize(this, true); /MainActivity.cs:

#### ソースコード

FirebaseIDService.cs

```
    class FirebaseIDService
    {
        [Service]
        [IntentFilter(new[] { "com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" })]
        public class FirebaseInstanceIDService : FirebaseMessagingService
        {
            public override void OnNewToken(string token)
            {
                base.OnNewToken(token);

                //token write to server.
            }
            :
```

MainActivity.cs

```
using Plugin.FirebasePushNotification;
:
    public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
            ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;

            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
            LoadApplication(new App());

            //Set the default notification channel for your app when running Android Oreo
            if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= Android.OS.BuildVersionCodes.O)
            {
                //Change for your default notification channel id here
                FirebasePushNotificationManager.DefaultNotificationChannelId = "FirebasePushNotificationChannel";

                //Change for your default notification channel name here
                FirebasePushNotificationManager.DefaultNotificationChannelName = "General";
            }

            #if DEBUG
                FirebasePushNotificationManager.Initialize(this, true);
            #else
                FirebasePushNotificationManager.Initialize(this,false);
            #endif

            //Handle notification when app is closed here
            CrossFirebasePushNotification.Current.OnNotificationReceived += (s, p) =>
            {
                //Console.WriteLine("Handle notification when app is closed here") ;
            };
        }
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<receiver android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdInternalReceiver" android:exported="false" />
<receiver android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdReceiver" android:exported="true" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
        <category android:name="${applicationId}" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
<meta-data android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon" android:resource="@drawable/ic_stat_ic_notification" />
```

**実行環境:**
Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2019   Version 16.8.3
Xamarin.Forms                       5.0.0.1874
Xamarin.Firebase.Messaging          121.0.1
Plugin.FirebasePushNotification     3.3.10

Answer (score 0):

自己解決しました。
Androidプロジェクトのプロパティ・Androidオプション・リンク中の指定を「なし」にしてビルドした版で、OnNewToken は作動しました。
但し、サイズ大のワーニングになっているので、なんとも切ないですが。